# Remove NaN for the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, nan

Given the sample df:

```
p = [[1.234,1], [2.2134,1.2365], [1.1234,2.5432]]
q = [[2,2], [0,1], [2,4]]
p[p == 22] = np.nan
```

I am able to remove `NaN` from `p` values by doing:

```
p = np.array([i for i in p if np.any(np.isfinite(i))], np.float64)
q = np.array(q, np.float64)
```

Can I do anything for a loop to check if there is a `NaN` and remove it?

But it is for one couple. What if I have the dataset like (real data is much more bigger`(106,1900)`)

df =

```
    1           1.1     2           2.1     3           3.1     4           4.1     5           5.1
0   43.1024     6.7498  NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN
1   46.0595     1.6829  25.0695     3.7463  NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN
2   25.0695     5.5454  44.9727     8.6660  41.9726     2.6666  84.9566     3.8484  44.9566     1.8484
3   35.0281     7.7525  45.0322     3.7465  14.0369     3.7463  NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN
4   35.0292     7.5616  45.0292     4.5616  23.0292     3.5616  45.0292             NaN         NaN
```

Comment: if you use pandas dataframe, you can use df.fillna() to replace nan with any value you provide

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html

Comment: Do you want to just remove all rows with `nan` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try for instance (in order to fill all NaN-s with 0's):

```py
df.fillna(0)
```

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: Impossible. Those 0 will identify location then

Comment: any fillna impossible in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can use your average or mean of each column to fill your NaN values

```
df.fillna(df.mean())
```